# Workflows working in test, but not in production

Tags: list, workflow, environment

I have a list that I have created with workflows to send me an email when a new item is added.  The workflows work in our test environment, but when I import the list into our production environment, the workflow does not work.  Initially I just recreated the list (including the workflows) in production, but the workflows didn't work, so I imported it.  Still nothing.

Comment: Is your out of the box alerts working in Production? Have you tried in a different web application/ site collection if you have more than one in your Production? See this article for workflow troubleshooting tips: https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Troubleshoot-workflow-errors-8fcf47e5-a410-4714-880b-2611b18a56ce

Comment: We do have workflows that are working in Production.  The article didn't list the problem I'm having.  It stated for 2007 that workflows aren't starting because of a System Account or submitting form via email.  We are 2010, and neither of those are the problem.  I'm not sure how to put it on a different site collection.  Not sure what to do to get these workflows to work.  We MUST have workflows working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this problem.  It was more of an Outlook problem than a SharePoint problem.  I had an Outlook rule that was set up to catch another incoming email and file it away.  The same rule was catching the emails I received from this workflow and filing them in the same place.
I checked with a coworker and he was not getting the emails either.  I stumbled upon this while doing a search for another email in Outlook.  I checked with another coworker of mine, and she said she got the emails and had been getting them all along.  I was telling my team to just ignore the emails coming in (referring to the TEST ones), because they were getting a bunch of emails.  Turns out, both me and my male coworker had rules set up that were filing these workflow emails in Outlook.  I've had issues with the Outlook rules not working properly in the past.  I've updated the rules now.  Problem solved.